# Safe gnosis api doesn't return safe by owner

Tags: gnosis-safe

I've created safe on Rinkeby network, and I want to get this safe through api by owner address, but i'm getting empty array[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're interacting with the mainnet transaction service. The rinkeby one is https://safe-transaction.rinkeby.gnosis.io

You can find the whole list here:
https://docs.gnosis-safe.io/backend/available-services